# Zero splits from non-zero paths

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running MapReduce job(Voldemort BuildAndPush but it probably doesn't matter) and I got 0 input splits from non zero input paths. My knowledge comes from the following part of the logs:

> 16/09/08 11:16:19 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1099
>
> 16/09/08 11:16:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0

My files are not empty. I wonder what is the cause of such behaviour...

Comment: How are you running the job?

Comment: what about number of mapper is it 0 too ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with AvroInputFormat:

```
* By default, when pointed at a directory, this will silently skip over any
* files in it that do not have .avro extension. To instead include all files,
* set the avro.mapred.ignore.inputs.without.extension property to false.
```